# MySQL - constraints on DATETIME field is not returning expected result

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Here is my test table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `thetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test` (`thetime`) VALUES ('2013-02-26 18:07:00');
INSERT INTO `test` (`thetime`) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO `test` (`thetime`) VALUES (NULL);
```

SELECT * FROM test:

```
id | thetime
------------------------
1  | 2013-01-01 00:00:00
2  | null
3  | null
```

SELECT * from test where thetime <> '2013-01-01 00:00:00':

```
id | thetime
------------------------
empty result set
```

I'm expected to get the 2 records with `null` value in the field `thetime`

```
id | thetime
------------------------
2  | null
3  | null
```

I'm wondering why I'm not getting this result has the value null is different than '2013-01-01 00:00:00'

Anyone knows?

Cheers, 
Maxime

Comment: Simplified, `NULL` is never equal or not equal to anything, it's just... `NULL`. The only (standard) expressions that work reliably with `NULL` are `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why you are getting empty result is because `null` aren't defined.

when you want to compare null values, use `IS NULL`

```
SELECT * 
from   test 
where thetime IS NULL OR
      thetime <> '2013-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE thetime <> '2013-01-01 00:00:00' 
   OR thetime IS NULL
```

See the documentation for further reading:

- [Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)
- [Problems with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-null.html)